# Angular form with multi selection table validate at least an item is checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular form see the image, how do I validate the form for at least one item is should be checked, I mean the save button should be disabled if no item is checked and enabled when item is checked.

```
  [![The form image][1]][1]
```

[image]

My form is reactive form and the table with Angular material multi selection table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm cusiosity about how use a material table together a FormControl. I supose you has some like:

```
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
  form=new FormGroup({
     country:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
     digits:new FormControl(null,,Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)),
     data:new FormControl(null,Validators.required)
  })
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.selection.changed.subscribe(res=>{
      this.form.get('data').setValue(
         res.source.selected.length?res.source.selected:null
      )
    })
  }
```

That's, if you has checked some row, the value of the control is an array with the rows selected, else null. So a simple Validators.required give you is some is selected

NOTE: If the only you want to take care is if some is selected you can use

```
<button [disabled]="selection.isEmpty()">save</button>

//or, if your form is simply
  form=new FormGroup({
     country:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
     digits:new FormControl(null,,Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4))
  })
//you can use
<button [disabled]="selection.isEmpty() || form.invalid">save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can bind the `ngModelChange` for checkboxes and write up a method to check if there is any item in the list with checkbox as checked (basically if the bound value is true).

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" (ngModelChange)="onSelect(item)">{{item.name}}
```

**TS**

```
 validate() {
    this.selected = this.list.filter(x => x.isSelected).length === 0;
  }

  onSelect(role) {
    this.validate();
  }
```

I created a quick stackbitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkboxlist-validation

Let us know if it helped.